# How do I get the date column to sort right with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to build a simple HTML table sorter using pure jquery and javascript without using any plugins but cannot get the date column to function right. 6/16/2015 and 1/1/2016 are not right, its almost like I am not sorting by every row. The other columns are coming out right but I cant figure out whats going on.

This is what I have so for:

Javascript:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    ('#HardSoftWareTbl thead').on('click', 'th', function () {
        $(this).attr('data-order', ($(this).attr('data-order') === 'desc' ? 'asc' : 'desc'));
        if ($(this).hasClass("dateTh")) {
            sorttable(this, $('#HardSoftWareTbl thead th').index(this), true);
        }
        sorttable(this, $('#HardSoftWareTbl thead th').index(this), false);
    });
});
function sorttable(header, index, isDate) {
    var tbody = $('table tbody');
    var order = $(header).attr('data-order');
    tbody.find('tr').sort(function (a, b) {
        var tda = $(a).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();
        var tdb = $(b).find('td:eq(' + index + ')').text();
        if (isDate) {
            tda = toDate(tda);
            tdb = toDate(tdb);
        }
        return (order === 'asc' ? (tda > tdb ? 1 : tda < tdb ? -1 : 0) : (tda < tdb ? 1 : tda > tdb ? -1 : 0));
    }).appendTo(tbody);
}
function toDate(d) {
    console.log("d: " + d);
    var date = d.split(" ")[0].split("/");
    console.log("date: " + date);
    return new Date(date[2], date[0] -1, date[1]);
}     
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<style>
table {width: 100%;font: 12px arial;}
th, td {min-width: 40px;text-align: center;}
th {font-weight: bold;}
 </style>
  <table id="HardSoftWareTbl" class="table">
<thead id="theader"  >
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Quantity</th>
        <th class="dateTh">Date Added</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Surface Book</td>
        <td>A portable tablet/laptop hybrid</td>
        <td>$1,899.99</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>6/16/2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Surface Studio</td>
        <td>A desktop computer.   Edit photos, videos, etc.</td>
        <td>$2,999.99</td>
        <td>87</td>
        <td>1/1/2016</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Visual Studio</td>
        <td>The best IDE around for software development using Microsoft technology</td>
        <td>$10,999.99</td>
        <td>N/A</td>
        <td>5/2/1999</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Visual Studio</td>
        <td>IDE for software development using Microsoft         technology</td>
        <td>$10,999.99</td>
        <td>01</td>
        <td>5/3/2000</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Initial table state:
[image]

First Click on Date Added
[image]

Last Click on Date Added
[image]

Comment: convert date to timestamp, and compare timestamp as integer,

Comment: I tried tda = Date.parse(tda);tdb = Date.parse(tdb); but I am getting the same problem

Comment: This seems like a duplicate to me here https://stackoverflow.com/q/10123953/125981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in your code is that, `sorttable` is getting called twice. Once with isDate set as true and immediately after with falsey value.

Added else block for:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("dateTh")) {
    sorttable(this, $('#HardSoftWareTbl thead th').index(this), true);
}
sorttable(this, $('#HardSoftWareTbl thead th').index(this), false);
```

to

```
if ($(this).hasClass("dateTh")) {
    sorttable(this, $('#HardSoftWareTbl thead th').index(this), true);
} else {
    sorttable(this, $('#HardSoftWareTbl thead th').index(this), false);
}
```

Otherwise it will sort twice.

Checkout the pen at:

https://codepen.io/ankur-agarwal/pen/QQKJJj

I did update the `toDate` assuming the format to be `MM-dd-yyyy`.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Pretty big derp, not sure why I got rid of the else.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your custom date comparator like following.

```
function dateComparator(date1, date2) {
    var date1Number = getComparableNumber(date1);
    var date2Number = getComparableNumber(date2);
    //Negative if date2 is bigger and possitive if date2 is smaller.
    return date1Number - date2Number;
}


function getComparableNumber(date) {
    if (date === undefined || date === null) {
        return null;
    }
    var dtSplit = date.split('/');
    var yearNumber = dtSplit[2];
    var dayNumber = dtSplit[1];
    var monthNumber  = dtSplit[0];
    return (yearNumber*10000) + (monthNumber*100) + dayNumber;

}
```

Here date is converted to a number like "1/1/2016" will be converted to 201601001. Now it's easy for your to order it.

If you are open for open source library, you can check [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). It is an excellent library for date handling.